# Amazon SNS to push topic using Java

Tags: java, amazon-web-services

I'm trying to implement push notifications on my Java-based website(Using Struts 1.x). The goal is to make something similiar to what Stackoverflow and other sites have which notify a user in real-time when they get messages.

I'm using mysql as my database, Apache as my server, and am considering using Amazon-SNS as the framework for these notifications since that is what that service seems to be intended for.

Comment: I don't see the actual question, here... only statements about what you are doing.  What are you asking, please?

Comment: i want sending push notifications from amazon sns to my website

Comment: @JNYRanger: If there is a problem with a post, please describe the problem in detail, instead of just posting "what have you tried". See [this Meta post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/172760/152134) on whether "what have you tried" comments are acceptable and alternatives to "what have you tried". Thanks!

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Did I miss something?  I don't think I posted a comment on this question.

Comment: @JNYRanger: it seems to have gone because I flagged it yesterday -- I think you had posted "What had you tried so far" to this question, since I had gone and flagged a number of these across Stack Overflow (in accordance with the post). Don't worry about it too much.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy Gotcha.  Yeah it was a over a week ago and probably forgot about it.  Just read the meta, guess I'll join "Team Help Describe Question Problems Better"

Answer (score 2):

On a "web site," no, that isn't what SNS really does.

SNS has two different modes of operation:

- "topics" -- sending broadcast notifications to a combination of web *servers* (not browsers) over http(s), email addresses, SQS queues, and SMS devices (text messages), that have confirmed their subscription to the SNS topic
- "mobile push" -- sending addressable push notifications directly to mobile apps you write (not to the web browsers directly)

For real-time notifications to browsers, take a look at the source of the page you're looking at right now for a hint of how it's done:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
StackExchange.ready(function () {
    StackExchange.realtime.init('wss://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com,ws://qa.sockets.stackexchange.com');
    StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToInboxNotifications();
    StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToReputationNotifications('1');
    StackExchange.realtime.subscribeToTopBarNotifications('1');
});
</script>
```

That looks like a [websocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) connection, identified by `wss://` (contrast with `https://`).  There are a variety of implementations of websockets, in various languages, that allow a component on your side to interact with the javascript running on the browser, and I would suggest that this is the closest thing to a standard mechanism for push notifications to modern web browsers.

SNS does not have a feature-set that offers this kind of integration to the browser, though it might be something you could use internally to relay messages from your application server to your websocket gateway(s), since SNS could provide a short-term buffer between the app server and the gateway, or the ability to broadcast a message to multiple gateways, if that's how you implemented it... the advantage of something like this would be that it would prevent the app server from being adversely impacted if the gateway were overloaded or offline.  Theoretically websockets can be terminated by the application server itself, since they begin their connection over HTTP, but the longer life of a typical websocket connection compared to an http request can make this a bad combination.